# What is Object[] exactly?

Tags: java

I am having difficulty understanding what an `Object[]` is. Is it an Array that keeps Objects ? For example what happens when we do this :

```
int a = 5;
String b = "Hi";
Object[] c = { a, b };
```

Did I just create an object with properties `a` and `b` added to it ? Or did I get an `Object` Array in which `a` and `b` was counted as objects and elements of this `c` the object array ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think `Object d = b;` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is not dynamically typed so you cannot add properties on the fly like in javascript ([without reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)). Btw. in java you dont call them properties, but instance-members/fields or methods if its a function, which are defined in [classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html) (but you usually work with instances which is constructed from a class). So `Object` is a class and `Object obj = new Object();`  `obj` is an instance

The notation `ClassName[]` always notates an array of type `ClassName`, so

```
Object[]
```

notates an array of objects. And

```
String[]
```

an array that can only contain Strings.

You can initialize an array with

```
Object[] objArr = new Object[3];
```

which creates a new empty array which can hold 3 elements. Or you can directly set the elements by

```
Object[] objArr = {"elem1","elem2","elem3"};
```

which creates an array with 3 elements (elem1-3). So therefore:

```
System.out.println(objArr[0]); //"elem1"
System.out.println(objArr[1]); //"elem2"
System.out.println(objArr[2]); //"elem3"
System.out.println(objArr[3]); // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Because you used `Object`as a type you can set practically anything to the array since any class automatically inherits from [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

```
Object[] objArr = {"elem1",2.34,new Date()};
System.out.println(objArr[0]); //"elem1"
System.out.println(objArr[1]); //2.34
System.out.println(objArr[2]); //11.05.2014
```

2.34 is a double, so a primitive, but since 1.4 java [autoboxes every primitive into its Object pendant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) (so [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)), thats why it works. Note that usually in a statically typed language you dont want to do that this way since you lose alle the advantages of statical type checks, so better define your types and use them.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you created an array of objects derived from Object (which is true for all object in Java), now containing an Integer (created by autoboxing) on position 0, and a String on position 1.

Answer (score 1):

> Did I just create an object with properties a and b added to it ?

No. Those are elements. **Properties != Elements.**

> did I get an Object Array in which a and b was counted as objects and elements of this c the object array ?

Little wrong. Counted as elements, which are objects.

```
  Object[] c = { a, b }; // a is Integer and b is String
```

When you write the above line, that means you created an array Objects with elements `a` and `b` in it. You can refer the array with `c`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it an Array that keeps Objects ?

To be precise, it's an Object that contains references to other Objects.

All objects in Java are created and live on the heap until the garbage collector reclaims them.  References point to those memory locations and give your program access.

The example you gave uses two immutable objects.  The real fun would happen if you chose a mutable object and added it to your array.

Answer (score 0):

On executing the program it will print,

> 5
>    Hi

on iterating the array. that shows the `Object` array consist of `a of Integer` and `b of String`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an array of objects. You've auto-boxed a from a primitive int into an Integer and added that, and String b to the Object array. Remember all Objects extend Object. Try casting the Objects to their subclass types and maybe this will help you understand what's going on. E.G.

```
int a2 = (Integer) c[0];
String b2 = (String) c[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Object[] is an array of object references. From your code, imagine you did this:

```
int a = 5;
String b = "Hi";
Object o1 = a; // Autoboxes to java.lang.Integer
Object o2 = b;
```

Pretty similar to:

```
int a = 5;
String b = "Hi";
Object[] c = new Object[2];
c[0] = a;
c[1] = b;
```

... right? Which is exactly what your code above does, in a more shorthand way. So, you create an array where each element holds a reference to an Object.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are superclasses of every non-primitive in Java. In your code:

```
int a = 5; // <- int is a primitive
String b = "Hi"; // <- String is a subclass of Object
Object[] c = { a, b };
```

*c* wants to have an array of Objects, and since *a* is an int, [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) occurs (this means that the compiler makes the int an Integer-object). You can compare it to the following code (this is basically what the compiler does behind the scenes).

```
int a = 5; // <- int is a primitive
String b = "Hi"; // <- String is a subclass of Object
Object[] c = { new Integer(a), b }; // <- int is autoboxed to it's container-class Integer
```

---

As I mentioned, Objects are the superclass of every non-primive in Java. So let's compare your code to the following:

I have three classes:

```
class C{ } // Just compare this with Object
class B extends C{ } // Compare this with String
class A extends C{ } // Compare this with Integer

// translating your code to:
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C[] c = { a, b };
```

The left side is the *reference type* and the right side is the *object type*.

```
// List is the reference type, ArrayList is the object type
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // (or List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); in Java 7+)

// With the C, B and A classes above:
// C is the reference type, A is the object type
C myClass = new A();
```